# UIElement in layered fashion

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, uielement

Technology : Silverlight
Platform : Windows Phone 7

```
foreach(Rectangle rec in listrect)
{
    Layoutroot.Children.Add(rec);
}
```

Done some mouse move capture events and made these rectangles draggable.

Each child element is added to the layout in some layered fashion I guess,where the first rectangle goes to the bottom layer next on top of that and on and on.

How can I avoid this and make all the `UIElement`s in same plane irrespective of the order in which they are added to child of the canvas?

Comment: How to avoid this and make all the UIelements in same plane irrespective of the order in which they are added to child of the canvas?

Comment: Tintu, this is how the system works... the items added to a panel later will be on top.

Answer (score 0):

Every element is drawn with a different ZIndex by Silverlight. If you don't specify the `ZIndex`, Silverlight assumes that the most recent elements added have a higher implied `ZIndex`. The same goes for XAML - elements below other elements have a higher implied `ZIndex`.

If you want to control the drawing of your Rect elements in your example, you'll need to modify the `ZIndex` manually. First, make sure your Layoutroot element is a `Canvas`. Next, in your mouse move event handlers, change the `ZIndex` dependency property to be higher.

For instance, this example will bring the selected rectangle to the forefront while its being dragged.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="WindowsPhoneApplication1.MainPage"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private readonly Random _rnd = new Random();
        private List<Rectangle> _listRect;
        private Rectangle _selectedRect;
        private int _selectedRectPrevZIndex;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LayoutRoot.MouseMove += Rectangle_MouseMove;
            CreateAndAddRectangles();
            AddRectangles();
        }
        private void CreateAndAddRectangles()
        {
            _listRect = new List<Rectangle>(10);
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var rec = new Rectangle {Height = 50, Width = 50};
                rec.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, i * 30d);
                rec.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, i * 30d);
                rec.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(
                    Color.FromArgb(255,
                                   Convert.ToByte(_rnd.NextDouble() * 255),
                                   Convert.ToByte(_rnd.NextDouble() * 255),
                                   Convert.ToByte(_rnd.NextDouble() * 255)));
                rec.MouseLeftButtonDown += Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown;
                rec.MouseLeftButtonUp += Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp;
                rec.MouseMove += Rectangle_MouseMove;
                _listRect.Add(rec);
            }
        }
        private void AddRectangles()
        {
            foreach (var rec in _listRect)
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rec);
        }
        private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var rec = sender as Rectangle;
            if (rec == null)
                return;

            _selectedRectPrevZIndex = (int)rec.GetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_selectedRectPrevZIndex);
            rec.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 100);
            _selectedRect = rec;
        }
        private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var rec = sender as Rectangle;
            if (rec == null || _selectedRect == null)
                return;

            rec.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, _selectedRectPrevZIndex);
            _selectedRect = null;
        }
        void Rectangle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_selectedRect == null)
                return;

            var pos = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot);
            _selectedRect.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pos.X);
            _selectedRect.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pos.Y);
        }
    }
}
```